# Team Members Panel of Team Viewer Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-explorer

Why do my Team Members appear on some computers but not others when I am in Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer?

Computer that hosts the TFS Server:

[image]

Other computer, same account:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is part of the TFS Power Tools. It is not installed by default.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Comment: Can this be installed to a computer that doesn't have TFS? That is, can I install it just to get the Visual Studio plugins?  Thanks

Comment: @TylerDeWitt: yes, you can (and should) install it on a machine that only has Visual Studio and not the TFS server.